# How to select the first group of elements separated by comma in a column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe called `newdf`. I want to create a new column `colC` with the first element separated by comma in `newdf[,"colB"]` , but with only include values that begin with ":p." and end with a comma,`,`) and get the the result with column `colC`.

```
newdf<-structure(list(colA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), colB = structure(1:3, .Label = c("EN1:c.12CTG:p.L287fs,ENSG:p.L287fs,ENSG:exon10:TG:p.L258fs", 
"TG:p.L28fs,TG:p.L28fs.TG:p.L28fs", "TG:p.L2fs,TG:p.L8fs"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("colA", 
"colB"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
 colA                                                       colB        colC
    a       EN1:c.12CTG:p.L287fs,ENSG:p.L287fs,ENSG:exon10:TG:p.L258fs  p.L287fs
    b                                 TG:p.L28fs,TG:p.L28fs.TG:p.L28fs  p.L28fs
    c                                              TG:p.L2fs,TG:p.L8fs  p.L2fs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` and match one more elements that are not a `:` (`[^:]+`) followed by a `,` (using the regex lookaround)

```
library(stringr)
newdf$colC <- str_extract(newdf$colB, "[^:]+(?=,)")
newdf$colC
#[1] "p.L287fs" "p.L28fs"  "p.L2fs"
```

Or to be a bit more precise, we match a `:` (using the regex lookaround) followed by 'p' followed by a `.` (`\\.`) followed by one more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]+`)

```
str_extract(newdf$colB, "(?<=:)p\\.[^,]+")
#[1] "p.L287fs" "p.L28fs"  "p.L2fs"
```

---

The same pattern can be used with `sub` using capture groups

```
sub("^[^p]+(?<=:)(p\\.[^,]+).*", "\\1", newdf$colB, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "p.L287fs" "p.L28fs"  "p.L2fs"
```